# How can I do a git diff on the current file with magit?

Tags: spacemacs, magit, git

I'd like to do a diff on the current file / buffer compared to the git repository.

Ideally a single function that could be called, or binded to a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Firstly, make sure you're aware of https://stackoverflow.com/a/17799517
2. If you want a Magit diff buffer for the current file, you can call `magit-diff-buffer-file` directly, or use the "diff" option (<kbd>d</kbd>) in `magit-file-popup`. e.g.:

   ```
   (global-set-key (kbd "C-c m d") 'magit-diff-buffer-file)
   (global-set-key (kbd "C-c m f") 'magit-file-popup)
   ```
3. You can alternatively invoke `vc-diff` with <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>

Comment: `(spacemacs/set-leader-keys "gfd" 'magit-diff-buffer-file)` A convenient binding for spacemacs.

Comment: AFAICS, `magit-file-popup` is no longer available, it's successor (in spirit at least) is `magit-file-dispatch`.

Answer (score 5):

If you have `ediff` set up properly (and you should!  it's awesome), then you can use `M-x ediff-revision` to run `ediff` for the current file against any of its revisions in Git, or in whatever VC system you use.

Comment: `ediff-revision` is awesome, you can do similar to IntelliJ's git diff on the current file, but perhaps even nicer once you "get it" (make sure to find the little help window by pressing `?` to see how you can manipulate the diff, and as usual, to quit press `q`!).